# Generate a sequence of time using R and lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate, tidyverse

Is there an efficient way to generate a time-sequence vector with `tidyverse` and `lubridate`? I know the two can work with `seq()` when one use the number of dates as the interval. For example, with the input:

```
seq(today(), today()+dyears(1), 60)
```

one can get a series of dates with a 60-day interval

```
"2017-02-14" "2017-04-15" "2017-06-14" "2017-08-13" "2017-10-12" "2017-12-11" "2018-02-09"
```

However, is there any way that this can work for **weeks**, **months** and **years** as well? Perhaps something similar to the code below, which I thought would work but did not:

```
seq(as_date(2000-01-01), as_date(2017-01-01), dyears(1))
```

> Error: Incompatible duration classes (Duration, numeric). Please coerce with `as.duration`.

I know it is possible to change `dyears(1)` into `365` or `30` if one only need an approximation for year or month, but was wondering whether there are smarter ways to take leap years and months into account.

---

To provide more context, I would like to generate a date vector so I can customize the `scale_x_date` in `ggplot`. Instead of letting the `waiver()` display 2000, 2003, 2006, 2009, I want the plot to have all individual years or even every three-month period if possible.

Comment: `seq(today(), today()+dyears(1), by='weeks)`

Comment: Just use `seq.Date`. It's a little magic; you can pass it `by = '2 weeks'` and it'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, @GGamba, I did not realize that one can specify 'weeks' and 'years' in `by=` for `seq()`

Comment: @alistaire, thanks. This works like a charm as well.

Comment: When you were at the `?seq` page you s _should_ have also followed the link to `?seq.Date` where the answer would have become obvious.

Comment: @42- that's totally fair. I should have looked into the documentation further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try using seq.Date():

```
seq.Date(from=as.Date("2000-01-01"), to=as.Date("2010-01-01"), by="month")
```

or:

```
seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
```